# Activate remote function in Mamp - entering the relative path

Tags: remote-server, mamp-pro

Hello — I´m trying to set the connection to import and export my existing (test)site. Unfortunaltely I´m struggling badly. Maybe because I do not have experience with relative paths and are just doing wrong. I hope you can help me and pass the correct entry for these two fields in the ”remote” section:

Server:...
Path:....

The absolute path to the folder where all the wordpress-files are in is:

rex23.flatbooster.com/html/test/

I put in 'Server': rex23.flatbooster.com

And then - as always alert 3014 is appearing - I tried many entries for 'Path'.

I am sure, I have the right and permission and my folder definitivily exists.

Please help! I did my research, but couldn´t solve it yet.
Thank you, Helma

Answer (score 0):

- You probably already tried `html/test/` as relative path
- Have you already tried connecting to the main domain with success?
- Another thing to look at is the way your hostingprovider handles subdomains, if you haven't done already so. Check your FTP with a FTP app to see if the subdomain rex23 is located in a subdirectory under flatbooster.com/rex23/. Or if it is a *real* subdomain in which case you would see /rex23 at the root of your ftp account (you sub-domain directory and main-domain directory would then reside in the same, like this:

  `-- private_dir
  -- flatbooster.com/html/
  -- rex23.flatbooster.com/html/`

  If the latter is **not** the case, then you could try to connect to main domain flatbooster.com (thus without the subdomain). And then use the relative path field in Mamp to get to your subdomain directory.